# Google Drive Android API not activating

Tags: android, google-api, android-emulator, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to add the ability to upload a text file to Google Drive to an existing android application. I've used the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) and integrated the activity into the app. When I click on the "Call Drive API" button in the emulator I get a 403 error saying "Access not configured" and suggesting I enable the Drive API at `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive/overview?project=` then an id number.

[image: 403 error message]

I've done that, and the developer console says the drive API is enabled, but I still get the 403 error in the app, even a few hours later.

[image: screenshot of google developer console]

Is there some step I'm missing or a way to get this working?

Comment: I ended up using the specifically android api instead of this REST one, and I was only ever able to connect with a signed app, (the debug key didn't seem to work.) Thanks for the help anyways. Maybe this question will help someone else?

Answer (score 1):

`403 Forbidden`, look like that your request to Drive API has missed an authorization token?

Please read [About Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth):

> Every request your application sends to the Drive API **must** include an
>   authorization token

At [Upload Files Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#simple), you will also find an simple example (pay attention to `Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token`):

```
POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

JPEG data
```